# Trying to build C++ exe that uses .so that uses other .so files

Tags: c++, linux, shared-libraries

I'm trying to build a C++ executable that links with a shared library, libA.so.  libA.so was built and linked with another shared library, libB.so.  libB.so was built using -rpath to look for a custom build of a system library in my home directory (liblapack.so).  If I do a "readelf -d" on libB.so, I see liblapack.so as "NEEDED", and I also see the custom build path listed under "RPATH".  If I do a "readelf -d" on libA.so, I only see libB.so listed as "NEEDED"; no RPATH entries.  When I then try to build my exe using libA.so, it is not looking in the custom path specified in libB.so; it's picking up the one in the system location, which doesn't have the right functions so the linking fails.  Does anyone know of a way to achieve what I want to do here?  Is there any way to get libB's RPATH entries to propagate to libA?

I'm using GCC 9 on RHEL 7.

Thanks in advance.

ETA: The app, libA, and libB are all separate packages, so I would prefer to keep their build processes and unusual rpath info known only to themselves. I can change the link flags of each black box.  They're also established packages, so I can't change to autoconf or something like that.

ETA2: Restating things, when I build libA and link with libB, it does mark libA as needing libB, which is great. Then an app can link with libA and implicitly get libB, which libA needs to function.  But why does linking libB with libA throw away libB's rpath info? Or, when app is linking, why doesn't it see that since libA requires libB, link with libB and preserve libB's rpath specification? The bottom line is that libB's rpath specification is being lost somewhere, and it seems like it shouldn't be.  (By the way: This is a new thing to me, so I don't doubt there are issues with the way I think it should work.  But logically, it sounds right to me.)

Comment: Did you try specifying the `-rpath` entries required when building `libA`?

Comment: I did not try specifying -rpath when building libA, but I'm assuming that would work. They're separate packages, so I'd like to avoid it if possible.  Maybe it has to be done.

Comment: There are tools that automatically take care of technical details like that. Tools like autmake and libtool take care of managing these kind of inter-package dependencies.

Comment: That's difficult considering these packages. Maybe it isn't the case, but couldn't the linker just carry libB's RPATH entries along with it? That would solve the problem, and it seems sensible.

Comment: It is unlikely that anyone can help answering a question unless all relevant information related to the question is included in the question itself. Otherwise, any offered suggestion will likely results in this kind of a "but this won't work because of <x> which I'm now mentioning for the first time" response, and waste everyone's time.

Comment: I thought the question was decent and self-contained, but yes, there are other mitigating issues that prevent other solutions from working.

Comment: It is hard to tell what exactly you are doing. Please build a [mre]. Four very short C files and a script to make three libraries and an executable.

Comment: I'll see what I can do about an example. In reality, app, libA, and libB are not small things, so I would have to create something from scratch. The libB example would also need to have an unusual rpath dependency. In the meantime, I hope my edits have clarified things.

Comment: `libB`'s rpath is used at the time `libB.so` is loaded and resolved - at runtime. If you can't keep all your lapack dependencies inside `libB`, you have some implicit coupling (that 3 "independent" shared objects all depend on lapack, and you can only load one version of that), and that coupling will need to be expressed somewhere.

Comment: In my case, the lapack dependency is only within libB, but I can see how it could get complicated if app, libA, or some other library also had an lapack dependency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `-rpath-link` when linking and specify your custom library location.

```
gcc -o app source.o -lA -Wl,-rpath-link=$HOME
```

This will cause the linker to look in `$HOME` to find shared libraries referenced by other shared libraries.  But only when linking.  At run time, when dynamic linking is done, the rpath-link option has no effect and the normal RPATH, LD_LIBRARY_PATH, etc. search order is used.

The `DT_RPATH` or `DT_RUNPATH` in a shared library ARE searched.  But they are not first in the search order.  Your alternate version of libB must be in a path that comes first, so it's found rather than the one you want.  Try renaming it and see what happens or perhaps check your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `LD_RUN_PATH` variables.

There isn't a way the change the order, but `-rpath-link` comes first, so this can fix the problem.

To make libB self contained, use something like a pkgconfig file that contains the options needed to use the library.  This also works for finding header files or with static libraries.

You could also rename libA to libMyA to avoid the name collision with the alternate version also installed.

Alternatively, one can avoid the link failure without really fixing the problem by using the `--allow-shlib-undefined` linker option.  Then it shouldn't matter if it finds the wrong version as the missing symbols won't be an error.

Comment: I actually did try that and it did indeed work. But as I mentioned later in a comment, the app, libA, and libB are all unrelated packages, so it's be nice to keep them as black boxes regarding each other. I understand this may not be possible the way the tools currently work. Thanks.

Comment: It looked like what you were tying to do was "build C++ exe", but I guess you wanted to do it without adding compiler flags.  Don't know of any way to get ld or gold to do this.  I think the assumption is that you should install system shared libraries in the system search path, which can be controlled a number of ways.  If the libraries are temporarily in an unusual location, for instance being run before being installed, they you are building them and can set linker flags to reflect this location.  If a libraries needs flags to use, then use something like pkgconfig to get them.

Comment: I should have explicitly mentioned in the question that I don't want app (or libA) to know about libB's strange rpath settings.  Sorry; I edited the question.  I can in general add compiler/linker flags to any individual piece.  The simple answer in this case appears to be, "it doesn't work like that".  Having said that, I'm curious why it doesn't.  It seems sensible.

Comment: The real issue here is that the search order used by `ld` is not the same as that used by `ld.so`.  The latter finds the library you want while the former does not.   I don't know of a way to alter this with the library itself rather than linker options.  I think the reason the orders are different is that it works better for the more normal case of building software in one location and then installing in another.

Comment: Unless I use -rpath-link or -rpath when building app or libA (like you did above), I can't build the app executable.  It complains that a few functions defined only in the lapack build in my home directory (and not in the system one) are undefined.  So I'm not sure that ld.so is involved?

Comment: `ld.so` is involved when you *execute* the executable.  If it used the same search path as `ld`, then even after using `-rpath-link` you would be unable to execute correctly because `ld.so` would find the incorrect shared library the same way `ld` also fails when not using `-rpath-link`.

Comment: I see.  When you brought up that the real issue relates to ld.so, I felt like, hey, I can't even build the executable yet!

Comment: I hadn't seen your expanded answer.  There's a lot of good info there, so I'm just going to mark that as the answer.  Thanks.